# How to include a static library inside my static library with makefile?

Tags: makefile, static-libraries

I have the following subdirectories:

```
libftprintf/
 -Makefile(1)
 -ft_printf.h
 -ft_printf.c
 -ft_printf_source1.c
 -ft_printf_source2.c
 -libft/
  -Makefile(2)
  -ft_atoi.c
  -ft_itoa.c
  -...
```

And what I want is to call makefile(2) (which gives me a `libft.a` file) from makefile(1) and add all under the same `libftprintf.a` file.
How do I go about to do this?

My makefile:

```
SRC_FILES:=$(wildcard *.c)

NAME=libftprintf.a

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

OBJ_DIR=obj

HDR=ft_printf.h

SRC_NAMES=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

SRC_NAMES_O=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(SRC_NAMES))

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@

%.o: %.c $(HDR) $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ 


$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_NAMES)
    ar -rc $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@

all: $(NAME)

bonus: all

clean:
    rm -rf obj/

sclean: clean

fclean: clean

re: sclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by copying the first library `libft.a` and renaming it `libftprintf.a` and then `ar -rcs` it with the object files.

My Makefile:

```
SRC_FILES:=$(wildcard *.c)

NAME=libftprintf.a

LIBFT=libft/libft.a

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

OBJ_DIR=obj

HDR=ft_printf.h

SRC_NAMES=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

SRC_NAMES_O=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(SRC_NAMES))

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@

%.o: %.c $(HDR) $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@ 

$(LIBFT):
    make -C libft

$(NAME): $(LIBFT) $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_NAMES)
    cp libft/libft.a $@
    ar -rcs $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)

all: $(NAME)

bonus: all

clean:
    rm -rf obj/
    make -C libft $@

fclean: clean
    rm -f libftprintf.a
    make -C libft $@

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re so
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to combine two static libraries together into a single static library, directly.  It's just not something that's supported by the toolchain.

If you are determined to do it the only way is to write a little script that will extract every object file from one of the libraries using `ar x` and add each one into the other library with `ar r`.